# Can't $_GET contents of field using quoteid

Tags: php, html, get

I am sending myself crazy figuring out what the issue is with the following code. All names within the database are exact as I have them here however I can't seem to get the info from the quote using $quoteid however when I type in an id static e.g. quoteid = 12 I can filter through the data.
Obviously this isn't ideal.

```
<?php
$quoteid = $_GET["quoteid"];    
if ($_GET['quoteid']) {
    $quoteid = $_GET["quoteid"];
}
$quote = $db->getRow("SELECT * FROM quotes WHERE quoteid = $quoteid");
?>
```

Html

```
<h1><?php echo $quote->description;?></h1>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Melissa

Comment: Why you got $quoteid twice? ^_^

Comment: You got so many mistakes in just a few lines of codes, unused assignments, sqlinjection...

Answer (score 1):

Note that you need to put the PHP **variables inside single quotes** when writing SQL queries.  Do it like in the example:

```
$quote = $db->getRow("SELECT * FROM quotes WHERE quoteid = '$quoteid'");
```

Answer (score 1):

why you getting again and again `$_GET["quoteid"]` and also use single for variable when writing SQL queries

```
<?php
$quoteid = $_GET["quoteid"];    
if (!empty($quoteid)) {
    $quote = $db->getRow("SELECT * FROM quotes WHERE quoteid = '$quoteid'");
}
else {
  echo 'quote id is empty';
}
?>
```

also use  `mysql_real_string_escape()` to prevent sql injection

Answer (score 0):

You should do the following... basic debugging.

1. `print_r` or `var_dump` for `$_GET` to see if and how "quoteid" is set up
   in the `$_GET` superglobal
2. `echo` your SQL (instead of `mysql_query` just `echo` it) and run it in
   phpmyadmin if it seems ok -- you might have something you missed out
   somewhere

That way you should be able to figure out your issue faster

Answer (score 0):

there is mistake in query syntax with $quoteid variable. you should use this one-

```
global $db;
$quote = $db->get_row("SELECT * FROM quotes WHERE quoteid ='".$quoteid."'");
```